# Wordpress plugin fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I downloaded this taxi booking plugin from Github but when I try to activate it on wordpress I get a fatal error and it doesn't let me activate it. You can find the plugin on https://github.com/mbejda/TaxiCabBookingSystem

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Braintree_Exception_Configuration' with message 'merchantIdneeds to be set' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-master/lib/Braintree/Configuration.php:117 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-master/lib/Braintree/Configuration.php(139): Braintree_Configuration::get('merchantId') #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-master/lib/Braintree/Configuration.php(157): Braintree_Configuration::setOrGet('merchantId', NULL) #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-master/modules/BookingSystemBrainTreeModule.php(32): Braintree_Configuration::merchantId(NULL) #3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-master/main.php(177): BookingSystemBrainTreeModule->__construct(Object(BookingSystem)) #4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-maste in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-master/lib/Braintree/Configuration.php on line 117
```

Any help to get this resolved would be appreciated.

UPDATE at Sunday 8th Feb @ 8:18pm.
I have added the Merchant ID on Configuration.php its giving me the same error I think, if not the same then very simular

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Braintree_Exception_Configuration' with message 'publicKeyneeds to be set' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-master/lib/Braintree/Configuration.php:117 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-master/lib/Braintree/Configuration.php(139): Braintree_Configuration::get('publicKey') #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-master/lib/Braintree/Configuration.php(162): Braintree_Configuration::setOrGet('publicKey', NULL) #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-master/modules/BookingSystemBrainTreeModule.php(33): Braintree_Configuration::publicKey(NULL) #3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-master/main.php(177): BookingSystemBrainTreeModule->__construct(Object(BookingSystem)) #4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-master/ma in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-master/lib/Braintree/Configuration.php on line 117
```

Regards

Comment: Have you tried setting the merchant id?

Comment: No I haven't, I am really new to wordpress plugins, what would I put there ?

Comment: Your, err, Braintree merchant id would be the most obvious thing to try first.

Comment: Is braintree some sort of payment gateway that I would need to sign up to? Then enter the email registered to merchant id?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the error message output... it says

> Message 'merchantId needs to be set' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DocklandsTaxi/wp-content/plugins/TaxiCabBookingSystem-master/lib/Braintree/Configuration.php

[Update]
Also check out https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php

Comment: Hi I have added the merchant id, now I get a similar message, please read the original post as the errors is too long to fit here

Comment: what are the other errors you should check out the braintreepayment docs to make sure you have everything setup correctly https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php